# Region (not country) codes for table rates shipping in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I'm adding table rates shipping method to a Magento install.
My rates are divided per weight in 6 different ranges **0-3 | 3-6 | 7-10 | 11-25 | 26-50 | 50-100** always the same in the whole Italy except for 3 regions.

In these regions prices for same weight ranges are slightly different. So It would be super good being able to add region codes into the right field, but **where I can find those codes**?

Headers into CSV are:

```
Country,Region/State,"Zip code","Weight (and Above)","Shipping Price"
```

I need to undrstand what I must add to the "Region/State" filed.
Adding different prices using Zip Codes would mean adding 7056 lines to my CV manually!

TNKS.

Comment: Yes you can add your region code in table rates refer this link [add region](http://www.sycha.com/magento-add-custom-state-province-region-country)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go and look at this table in your magento database;

```
select * from directory_country_region
```

This reveal all the regions currently in your store;

```
1   US  AL  Alabama
2   US  AK  Alaska
3   US  AS  American Samoa
4   US  AZ  Arizona
5   US  AR  Arkansas
6   US  AE  Armed Forces Africa
7   US  AA  Armed Forces Americas
8   US  AE  Armed Forces Canada
9   US  AE  Armed Forces Europe
10  US  AE  Armed Forces Middle East
```

etc. Column C is the region code.  You can add to this if required.

Comment: OK tnks! So there is no Regions for Italy, can I add them manually here?